# Any recommendations as to grouping this table in Reporting Services?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I'm just starting with Reporting Services so please take that into consideration.

I'm trying to make a report that groups by Nominee. I also want to group by Nominator i.e. so that if a Nominee has the same Nominator twice then it displays only ONE row instead for two and it increments field Number of Nominations (I get I need to use COUNT() here) and adds the total points of both (which I suspect I need to use SUM() on).

This is my table (on top) and the one I want to display on the bottom.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KhmoD.png

Notice on the top table that Janine and Rose have 2 different nominations with the same Nominator, therefore on the bottom table they display counts 2 on number of nominations and the sum of the points for both of the nominations.

So far I've tried this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UEqpM.png

How can I make it so I can include name, Dept, points and number of nominations in between groups? I've tried inserting text boxes but it doesn't work. Is there a better way to do this?

Also I'm using a Tablix

Answer (score 0):

Just create one group by option that takes the Nominee Name / ID, and display the name.
Within the details section add each nominator name.  In the footer of the Nominee Name group just add `=COUNT(Fields!NominatorID.Value)`

It would end up with something like this:

[image]

Comment: The problem is that I have to display all of the columns that you see in the image that way, otherwise I would have made the change

Comment: @Nimchip - No problem just add the columns in the header group of the Nominee name as `=First(Fields!MyColumn.Value)`